# React Native initial project doesn't run for IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, flipper

I created a new project using the command `npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`.

`"dependencies": { "react": "17.0.1", "react-native": "0.64.0" }`

When i run `npx react-native run-ios`, it gives me below error.

[image]

I tried replacing `use_flipper!()` with `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })`
in **Podfile** and then removed **ios/Pods** and **ios/Podfile.lock**.

[image]

When I run **pod install**, it is again throwing an error like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update flipper to 0.49 , that should do the trick

Comment: I tried using use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.1' }). Still i get the same build error.